# Sequelize join with group by

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

What I want to do would be best illustrated by a small example.

Say I have the following tables:

**Table Item**

- id
- name

**Table Review**

- id
- rating
- itemId

Obviously there are many Reviews to one Item.

How do I write a query which returns the following two columns:

- An item's name (`Item.name`)
- The sum of all an item's ratings (`Sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('rating'))`)

I'd like to use the ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
Review.belongsTo(Item, {foreignKey:'itemId', as : 'reviews'});
Item.hasMany(Review, {foreignkey:'id'});

Item.findAll({attributes:[['id', 'id'],['name', 'name'],[Sequelize.fn('SUM', 'rating'), 'total']], include:[{model:Review, as : 'reviews', required:true}], group:['id'], order:[Sequelize.fn('SUM', 'rating'), 'DESC']}).success(function(result){
    // return array;
    // total     -----> result[i].total
    // item name -----> result[i].name
})
```